# SvelteKit: configure a whole bunch of redirects in code instead of file-based routes

Tags: sveltekit

In my SvelteKit project I have quite a few redirects from old URLs to new URLs, done via the normal file based router. I create a `/src/routes/my-old-url/+page.ts` file with this code:

```js
import type { PageLoad } from "./$types";
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export const load: PageLoad = async () => {
  throw redirect(302, "/my-new-url/");
};
```

But I now have many of these files all over the place, and it's annoying to work with. I also don't have a good overview of all the redirects in the entire website. It would be much nicer if I could have an object with all redirects:

```
export const redirects = {
    "/old-url-1/": "/new-url-1",
    "/subpage/old-url-2/": "/new-subpage/new-url-2",
    // ...
}
```

Just save this in a file somewhere and dynamically handle all the redirects instead of having to create all these route files.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by first creating `src/lib/redirects.js`:

```js
export const redirects = {
    "/old-url-1/": "/new-url-1",
    "/subpage/old-url-2/": "/new-subpage/new-url-2",
    // ... and so on for all my redirects
};
```

Now, in my `src/hooks.server.js` I added:

```js
import { redirects } from './path-to-your-redirects-file/redirects.js';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    // If the path doesn't end in a slash, then add it as in the redirects.js file I have all paths ending in a slash
    if (!event.url.pathname.endsWith('/')) {
        event.url.pathname += '/';
    }

    const newPath = redirects[event.url.pathname];
    if (newPath) {
        const headers = new Headers({
            location: newPath,
        });
        return {
            status: 302,
            headers,
        };
    }

    // If no redirect is necessary, continue with the normal resolve process
    const response = await resolve(event);
    return response;
};
```

Worked for me with Svelte 3.53.1 and SvelteKit 1.0.0 pretty old project not updated to the latest.

Comment: Yeah I ended up with something very similar

Answer (score 0):

See the [hooks documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks), you can create a `handle` function in `src/hooks.server.js` to intercept all requests and add your redirects there.

Comment: According to the documentation, the handle hook can only be added to `hooks.server.js`. So a redirect wouldn't happen if it was during client-side browsing, only the initial request would be handled and possibly redirected.

Comment: Shouldn't that be what you want? The client code should not have any links to your old routes, i would assume.

Comment: Normally not, but links in old blog articles might still have them.

Comment: Damn, can't redirect from within `+error.svelte` :(